# Quick and easy way to post to Facebook using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, social-networking

I am trying to post some text from a `textarea` and a link to Facebook without using the SDK. The reason I can't use the SDK is that I can't add the channel.html to the site's root. Is there a simpler way to post something to a Facebook page? It must be able to post to a page as well as a feed.  It would also be handy to have the solution be able to post to Twitter, Google+, and Pinterest (Pinterest is not as important). I am hoping that there is some JavaScript library out there that lets you easily post to social media sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using the SDK works without a channel file, it just might not be as performant.
Second of all, the channel file doesn't have to be in your root directory, you can place it as far down your site's directory hierarchy as you want – it just has to be loaded from the same domain and via the same protocol, maybe that's your misunderstanding right there …?

Comment: The reason I can't put it on my site is because it is actually for a Firefox addon that modifies a webpage. I hadn't realized I could just do without; I will try that. It would still be handy if somebody would write a social media library.